# What does she mean if a woman says this to a man, "Did you park your white horse outside?"

Tags: sentence-meaning

It's actually from a dialogue of one episode of AMC's Mad Man (7th Season, E6), spoken by Peggy  somewhat acidly to Don when he entered her office room.

I just can't understand what does she mean in this sentence. "white horse" must be metaphoric here I guess, isn't it? But what is Peggy going to say in this sentence?

Anything to do with "a prince on white horse"? If that is the case, then she is satirizing him？

Comment: I'm not familiar with the program so I can't be sure, but this is almost certainly an allusion to the prince-on-a-white-horse trope. If so, yes, she is sarcastically implying he's a cad.

Comment: Now I think she maybe saying, "Do you want to act as a perfect hero here?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A slightly fuller quote is the following:

> Peggy (speaking to Don): Did you park your white horse outside? Spare me the suspense and tell me what your save-the-day plan is.

**A man riding a white horse is a trope/myth/metaphor/expression for "the perfect man", such as "Prince Charming", "A Knight in Shining Armor", or "My Hero".**

"Did you park your white horse outside?" doesn't have enough context to determine if it's flirtatious, ironic, pessimistic, optimistic, sarcastic, or even semi-literal -- a person who owns a white horse!   It's difficult to tell *exactly* what this means unless one knows the characters, their history, etc (which I do not).

**The writer is continuing to build her character and her relationship to Don.** Peggy is asking Don how he's going to handle a problem, but she's using metaphorical language that they both understand.  However, "spare me the suspense" and "save-the-day plan" are at the meta-level of identifying-the-trope.  She is expressing her attitude about both him and the situation in a creative manner.

**So she's the type of person (character) that can get away with referring to him in a metaphorically teasing manner - like a back-handed compliment.** She might see him as someone who has saved-the-day before, but in any case, she's calling him out on his attitude or her belief about his attitude. But this can also signal a close relationship because she is free to say this. **So while it's mild sarcasm, there may also be some bonding, friendship, or romantic undertones.**

Comment: Can't help adding that given the era in which Mad Men is set, you could include the Lone Ranger in that list. Hi-Yo Silver!